# Access Queries surrounding specific date yet changing year

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I am helping out a client with their database and am having some problems generating the criteria in the query section. I need the criteria to be "2018" if it is before 01/09/2017 and 2019 if it is after 01/09/2017 however it then needs to change to 2020 after 01/09/2018. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you want to subtract 9 days and then add some appropriate amount (1 or 2 years).  You can do this using `dateadd()`.  So, something like this:

```
select year(dateadd("day", -9, coldate)) + 1
```

Note:  If your date really means September 1st and not January 9th, then use months instead of days.  The idea still holds:  subtract an interval and then use the `year()` function.

Comment: I did mean sep 1st so would it be select year(dateadd("month", -1, year())) + 9    ?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a function that "converts" calendar days to days of the financial year:

```
Public Function DateFinancial( _
  ByVal Date1 As Date) _
  As Date

  ' End month of financial (fiscal) year.
  Const EndMonth    As Long = 8

  Dim ResultDate    As Date

  ResultDate = DateAdd("m", 12 - EndMonth, Date1)

  DateFinancial = ResultDate

End Function
```

Thus, to obtain the financial year of a calendar date:

```
FinancialYear = Year(DateFinancial([YourDateField]))
```

As you need the year after, add one year:

```
FinancialYearNext = Year(DateFinancial([YourDateField])) + 1
```

or:

```
FinancialYearNext = Year(DateFinancial(DateAdd("yyyy", 1, [YourDateField])))
```